# Strange characters after pressing numeric keyboards in VIM editor

Tags: terminal, vim, xterm

I'm running VIM under GNU screen. When I'm in insert mode and press e.g. asterisk symbol on numeric keyboard, instead of asterisk I get `<F3>`, when I press e.g. `4` I get `t` followed by newline. My `TERM` is set to `screen`. Same thing happens when VIM is not under screen and `TERM` is set to `xterm`. VIM is version 7.3.547. Screen is version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06. Where is the problem? I'm connecting to OS via Putty. I've find [this](https://superuser.com/questions/565178/how-do-i-get-the-numpad-to-work-in-vim-using-iterm2-on-osx-with-term-xterm) answer which suggests:

> Preferences->Profiles->Keys and load preset of: xterm with numeric keypad.

The problem is I do not know where are those preferences.

Comment: The corresponding Stack Overflow question is *[Using numpad in Vi (Vim) via PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274961/using-numpad-in-vi-vim-via-putty)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found solution [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PuTTY_numeric_keypad_mappings). In general:

- Run PuTTY Configuration.
- In the left pane, select Terminal, Features.
- Put a check mark next to "Disable application keypad mode".
- In the left pane, select Session.
- Save the settings.

Comment: NOTE: The bug is that Vim enables Application Keypad Mode without defining any mappings for it. I haven't found an explanation for this behavior. PuTTY, Terminal and XTerm are behaving correctly: they emulate a terminal with AKM and Vim asks for it to be enabled, so it is.